# Qual a diferença dos métodos apply, call e bind na hora de chamar uma função no Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Algumas vezes eu uso esses métodos mais não sei qual a diferença entre eles (e quero saber para que serve exatamente).

```
function load( arg ) {
    console.log( this, arguments );
}

load.apply('www', 'sss');
load.call('www', 'sss');
load.bind('www')
```

Se eu tiver esquecido de algum pode colocar também.

Comment: Se você também quiser dar um lida neste artigo do Smashing Magazine sobre o [function.prototype.bind](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/23/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/), vale a pena a leitura.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

São todo protótipos do objeto `Function` onde tem como objetivo executar uma função passando por ela um diferente contexto e argumentos.

- **call**: contexto, param1, param2, param3, ...
- **apply**: contexto, array de parametros

Já o **bind** ele é um pouco diferente e mais novo, nem todos browsers tem suporte, ele vai criar um "wrapper" da sua função, resultando em uma nova função, com contexto e argumentos fixos.

Por exemplo:

```
function foo(nome, idade) { return 'ola '+nome+', você tem '+idade}

var joao = foo.bind(window, 'joao');
joao('23'); // ola joao, você tem 23
joao('26'); // ola joao, você tem 26

// o que é o mesmo que:
var joao = function (idade) {
    return foo('joao', idade);
}
// porém evita bastante rescrita no seu código
// mantive o argumento nomeado como `idade` para fins didaticos o que
// é feito na realidade é não passar argumentos e o segundo argumento em
// foo seria `arguments[0]` dentro da função anonima do joao que é um wrapper
```

Voltando ao call e apply que são muito parecidos, vamos falar de contexto.

```
pessoa = { 
    idade: 10, 
    bar: function (nome) { 
        return 'ola '+nome+', vc tem '+this.idade+' anos';
    }
};

pessoa2 = {
    idade: 20
}

pessoa.bar('joao'); // ola joao, vc tem 10 anos

// Pessoa 2 não tem o método bar, mas podemos usar da pessoa emprestado
pessoa.bar.call(pessoa2, 'joao'); // ola joao, vc tem 20 anos

//ou com apply

pessoa.bar.apply(pessoa2, ['joao']);  // ola joao, vc tem 20 anos
```

Call é muito bom pra transportar argumentos de um método pra outro.

```
function fazerAlgo(callback, arg1, arg2) {
    var args = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 1);
    return callback.apply(this, args);
}

fazerAlgo(function (arg1, arg2) {
    console.log(arg1);
    console.log(arg2);
}, 'foo', 'bar');
// Escreve no console:
// 'foo'
// 'bar'
```

Comment: Eu vi que: call(context, array) e apply(context, p1, p2, p3). Se eu usar call como aplly, podem dar erros?

Comment: se vc usar no call, teu primeiro parâmetro vai ser uma array, se vc colocar terceiro parâmetro no apply, vai dar erro.

Comment: ah certo, **obrigado** :D