# Funcao() X Funcao.call()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ao analisar código de plugins Javascript/jQuery, costumo ver funções sendo invocadas com `.call()`. 
Entendo que ao chamar as funções dessa maneira, o primeiro parâmetro passado é o `this` (no caso, o provedor da chamada da função).
O que eu gostaria de saber, é se essa é, realmente, a única diferença entre usar `variavel.funcao()` e `variavel.funcao.call()`.
Se essa não for a única diferença, quais são as outras? Quais as situações preferíveis para usar cada um dos métodos?

Comment: Conhece o apply? É parecido com o call mas tem uma utilidade adicional.

Comment: @bfavaretto Pelo que li antes de fazer a pergunta, a diferença reside na passagem de argumentos, certo? Ou há mais algo?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como não perder o "this" do objeto atual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151201/3635) e [Qual a diferença dos métodos apply, call e bind na hora de chamar uma função no Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4340/3635)

Comment: Sim, a diferença é só essa. É que essa passagem dos argumentos como array abre novas possibilidades em relação ao call ou à invocação direta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, é. A "unica" utilidade do `call` é passar o this para forçar um contexto de execução seguido dos argumentos.

Gostava de responder mais completo, mas não há muito mais a dizer creio :)

Pela tua descrição compreendes a utilidade, mas um exemplo é uma gambiarra antiga para converter coleções de elementos que vêm de por exemplo `document.getElementsByTagName`, ou `document.querySelectorAll` numa array:

```
var elementos = [].slice.call(colecao);
```

O que isso faz é chamar o método `.slice` dessa array passando-lhe `colecao` como `this`, o que faz com que o JavaScript trate a `colecao` como uma array e a copie.

---

Parecido com o `.call` é o `.apply` que faz o mesmo mas em vêz de passarmos os argumentos depois do `this` um a um, podemos passar uma array:

```js
function log(teste, a, b, c) {
  console.log(this, teste, a, b, c);
}

log.call({
  metodo: 'call'
}, 'testeA', 1, 2, 3);

log.apply({
  metodo: 'apply'
}, ['testeB', 1, 2, 3]);

// e depois há maneiras mais modernas :)

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
log.apply({metodo: 'apply destructured'}, ['testeC', ...arr]);
```

Answer (score 3):

`.call()` invoca a função num escopo definido por você e permite que você passe os argumentos um a um (você pode setar o escopo da função e passar os parâmetros ao mesmo tempo). Por exemplo

```
var person1 = {firstName: 'Jon', lastName: 'Kuperman'};
var person2 = {firstName: 'Kelly', lastName: 'King'};

function say(greeting) {
    console.log(greeting + ' ' + this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName);
}

say.call(person1, 'Hello'); // Hello Jon Kuperman
say.call(person2, 'Hello'); // Hello Kelly King
```

Os objetos `person1, person2` são o escopo/contexto/`this` que você seta para função `say()`, e logo em seguida consegue passar o `greeting`, que é o parâmetro.

Aconselho ler [este artigo](https://codeplanet.io/javascript-apply-vs-call-vs-bind/), ele é bem explicativo e traz mais duas formas de setar o escopo de uma função.