# como utilizar o bind, call ou apply nesse contexto?

Tags: javascript

```
function Contador () {
   this.num = 0;
   var obj = this;

     this.timer = setInterval (function add () {
     obj.num++;
     console.log (obj.num);
   }, 1000);
}

var b = new Contador();
```

Não consigo entender direito como usar essas funções, nesse código que fiz, tem alguma maneira de referenciar o `this` ao Contador sem atribuir para uma variável ?

*Se alguém souber de algum bom lugar para aprender mais sobre o uso do `this` e essas funções, fico grato!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... tem alguma maneira de referenciar o this ao Contador sem atribuir para
>   uma variável ?

Sim, utilizando uma *Arrow Function* em vez de uma função normal. Se ler [na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) irá ver que a *Arrow Function* não muda o `this`:

> An arrow function does not have its own this; the this value of the enclosing execution context is used

Traduzindo

> Uma arrow function não tem o próprio `this`; o `this` utilizado é o do contexto em que ela se encontra.

Veja como fica:

```js
function Contador () {
   this.num = 0;

   this.timer = setInterval (() => { //arrow function aqui
     this.num++; //this aqui refere Contador
     console.log (this.num); //e aqui também
   }, 1000);
}

var b = new Contador();
```

Há casos em que este comportamento se torna uma desvantagem, quando é necessário que a função tenha o seu próprio `this`. No seu caso acaba por facilitar.

Quanto ao `bind`, `call` e `apply` a questão indicada já detalhe bastante:

[Qual a diferença dos métodos apply, call e bind na hora de chamar uma função no Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4340/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-dos-m%C3%A9todos-apply-call-e-bind-na-hora-de-chamar-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no)

Answer (score 2):

A função `Contador()` foi atribuída ao objeto `b`, use dentro do `setTimeout` o objeto `b` que representa essa função. O efeito será o mesmo que o `this` do escopo da função `Contador()`:

```js
function Contador () {
   this.num = 0;

     this.timer = setInterval (function add () {
     b.num++;
     console.log (b.num);
   }, 1000);
}

var b = new Contador();
```

Um bom artigo sobre o **this** você pode ver [**neste link**](http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/javascript/this-javascript-dominando/).

Comment: Não seria `setInterval` ? Rsrs

Comment: @wmsouza Não, ele quer o `this` do `Contador()` rs

Comment: Você disse na resposta: ***use no `setTimeout` o objeto b*** e no snippet esta `this.timer = setInterval`

Comment: @wmsouza eu quis dizer "dentro"... coloquei a palavra na resposta para evitar mal entendimento.