# Métodos call e apply em composição funcional

Tags: javascript, funções, composição

Eu queria saber como os métodos `call` e `apply` se comportam, principalmente quando um é passado como argumento de outro, e entender um pouco da lógica desse código, principalmente na linha em que eles foram chamados.

```js
function compose(f, g) {
    return function () {
        return f.call(this, g.apply(this, arguments)); /* não entendo essa linha */
    };
}

var square = function (x) {
    return x * x;
};

var sum = function (x, y) {
    return x + y;
};

var squareofsum = compose(square, sum);
console.log(squareofsum(2, 3));
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Qual a diferença dos métodos apply, call e bind na hora de chamar uma função no Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4340/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-dos-m%c3%a9todos-apply-call-e-bind-na-hora-de-chamar-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-no)

Comment: não, eu sei como ele funciona eu só não consegui  entender qual a lógica desses métodos na função.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, deve-se entender o que é a função `compose` que está implementada pelo código. Veja que ela espera dois argumentos (duas funções) e retornará uma nova função — a [função composta](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composi%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es) criada a partir da composição das duas fornecidas.

Observe que a função `compose` retorna uma nova função (a função composta):

```
function compose(f, g) {
  // Essa função é o resultado da composição de `f` e `g`.
  // Está sendo retornada.
  return function () {
    // ...
  };
}
```

Mas note que essa função que está sendo retornada não espera, explicitamente, nenhum argumento. Então como podemos chamar `squareofsum` passando argumentos como `2` e `3`? Os argumentos estão sendo obtidos a partir do objeto *array-like* [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Analisando um pouco mais a fundo, vamos agora a esta expressão, que é a primeira a ser avaliada:

```
g.apply(this, arguments);
```

Ela basicamente está invocando a função `g` passando os argumentos que você passou para a função composta. Como `arguments` é um objeto *array-like*, o `apply` é ideal nesse caso, uma vez que `apply` aceita, em seu segundo argumento, um array de parâmetros ordenados a serem passados durante a aplicação da função.

Veja este exemplo mais simples para entender o que acontece:

```js
function myFunc() {
  console.log(arguments);
  
  // Aplicaremos os argumentos à `console.log`:
  console.log.apply(console, arguments);
}

myFunc(1, 2, 3);
```

Com isso, a expressão `g.apply(this, arguments)` retornará o valor da função `g` quando aplicada utilizando os argumentos passados para a função composta.

Em seguida, esse valor retornado será utilizado como argumento para a função `f`. De modo mais simples, o que está ocorrendo é isto:

```
function compose(f, g) {
  return function () {
    const resultOfG = g.apply(this, arguments);
    return f.call(this, resultOfG);
  };
}
```

Em suma, esse método de composição funcional é basicamente chamar `f` com o resultado da aplicação de `g` com alguns argumentos. Algo assim:

```
f(g(2, 3));
```

---

Como curiosidade, a [construção sintática `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (nesse contexto chamada de parâmetros *rest*) pode tornar o uso de `arguments` desnecessário na maioria das vezes. Uma outra forma de se implementar aquele `compose` é:

```
function compose(f, g) {
  return function (...args) {
    return f(g(...args));
  };
}
```

Comment: a minha resposta tem uma abordagem mais direta mas você detalhou muito bem a explicação, ótimo trabalho

Answer (score 3):

O nome desse recurso é composição e é utilizado principalmente em programação funcional, não encontrei um artigo em português, em inglês tem o artigo [*Function Composition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)) na Wikipedia.

Essencialmente consistem em combinar duas ou mais funções em uma terceira função que executa as demais funções em uma determinada ordem.

A sua função `compose` faz composição de outras duas funções retornando uma nova função que combina as duas que foram passadas como argumentos. `call` e `apply` são usados para permitir essa lógica acontecer.

Foi usado `apply` na função de soma, e o retorno da soma usado no `call` da função de potência.